# Is is possible to suppress UNION when several join types are required?

Tags: mysql, sql

A simple example, I would like to retreive all black books and white cds that I'd sold :

Table things

```
id    |  name  |   type  |  color
---------------------------------
100      name1     book     black
200      name2       cd     white
300      name3       cd     black
400      name4       pc     black
```

Table books

```
id   |  thing_id  |  sold
-------------------------
1         100         true
```

Table cds

```
id    | thing_id  |  sold
-------------------------
1         200         false
2         300         true
```

The request could be :

```
select name, type from things t
join books b on b.thing_id = t.id
where t.color = "black" and  b.sold is true
UNION
select name, type from things t
join cds c on c.thing_id = t.id
where t.color = "white" and  c.sold is true
```

Ok the shema may be weird, but imagine additional tables of items (pcs, watches, etc .. ) requiring a new UNION each, so I wonder if there's a way to soften the joins to buid a request without any UNION (and maybe more efficient)

Comment: You might consider changing all the thing tables into one tables of lets say "Inventory"

Answer (score 0):

You could change the logic to:

```
select t.name, t.type
from things t
where (t.type = 'book' and t.color = 'black' and
       exists (select 1 from books b where b.thing_id = t.id and b.sold)
      ) or
      (t.type = 'cdes' and t.color = 'white' and
       exists (select 1 from cds c where c.thing_id = t.id and c.sold)
      ) or
      . . .
```

This saves the `union` in your version of the query.  The subqueries can also use indexes on `(thing_id, sold)` in the other tables.

Comment: With my shema, there are 5 "items" tables" and many more conditions. I'm going to test performance of this vs union thansk!

Comment: @troubadour . . . You want the indexes on the underlying tables.

Comment: Indexes are not the problem, there are many. Replacing joins by "where .. exists" can't be complete. For example ```join itemobjectrelationship ior on ior.objid = obj.objid join items it on it.it_name = ior.it_name``` here the joins allow a equality test between 2 joined fields on it_name.

Comment: @troubadour . . . I have no idea what the code is in your comment.  This addresses the question that you have asked and it has no `itemobjectrelationship` table.

Comment: I've just post a more simple code for the example which not includes an equality test between joins, but you can imagine a second join like this for books : `join authors a on a.name = b.authorname`

Comment: @troubadour . . . If you have a *different* question, ask a *new* question with appropriate explanation, sample data, and desired results.